# Problem with CREATE SECURITY POLICY in SQL Server 2014 SP3

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a security policy with this query:

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security.DegreeFilter 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE Security.fn_securitypredicate(Degree) ON Students
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Unknown object type 'SECURITY' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near 'FILTER'.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 SP3.
`SELECT @@version` returns `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3)`.
`compatibility_level` for my database is `120`.

Comment: According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-security-policy-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `Applies to: SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later`

Comment: you are right. i don't know why i assumed that it will work on 2008 and later.

Comment: @Squirrel, Please add this as answer, so it will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-security-policy-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`CREATE SECURITY POLICY` only applies to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later